# How do I show a tree with all kind of different nodes in Vaadin 24?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin24

Earlier versions of Vaadin used to have an actual tree component, like in Vaadin 6 (https://vaadin.com/download/book-of-vaadin/vaadin-6/html/components.tree.html) But the current component set does not have a Tree.

There is TreeGrid, which seems to be more like a table with one level of child nodes that -weirdly enough- have to be of the same Class as the table itself (given it needs to share the addColumns with the toplevel). At least I can't seem to figure out how to make it work with a different class as the child nodes.

And there is a 3rd party add-on (https://vaadin.com/directory/component/tree) but that also seems to support a tree of one class (Departments in the example).

I can of course hack this by using some kind of TreeNode intermediate class. But IMHO If you create a tree that takes domain objects as input, you would expect a renderer-class logic, and support for multiple classes in the same tree.

So suppose I have a domain with cities, streets, buildings, appartements, and rooms, how would I represent that in a 5 level deep tree structure in Vaadin (24+)?

Answer (score 0):

The thinking behind `TreeGrid` is to let the Java type system help you avoid programming mistakes. You can always opt out from type safety on that level by using `Object` as the item type (i.e. as `TreeGrid<Object>`) and handling the differences between different types with `instanceof` checks in various places.

The other alternative is like you mentioned to make the types explicit by introducing some kind of `TreeNode` class (or even a class hierarchy). In either case, you typically end up with roughly the same amount of code and it's mostly a subjective question on how you want to structure it.

Comment: But TreeGrid only supports one sublevel? One cannot define a HierarchyColumn on a HierarchyColumn?

Comment: There is always just a single hierarchy column - hierarchy comes from the data itself rather than from the column. The `setItems` shorthand used in most documentation examples only support a single sublevel. You can use `TreeData` or `TreeDataProvider` for deeper hierarchies.

Comment: That is totally not confusing , but I'll give it a try.